# phonenumbers - check phone number validity for any country

Tags: python, phone-number, pii

I am using the `phonenumbers` module to detect if a number is a valid phone number. I would like my script to consider all possible countries (that is, all possible national prefixes) when doing so. How can I do that?

At the moment, I can only detect the validity of a phone number for a specific country (US in the example below).

```
import phonenumbers
phone_number = phonenumbers.parse('987654321', 'US')
valid = phonenumbers.is_valid_number(phone_number)
```

Comment: After a little bit of searching, you can just remove the 'US' and still get if it is a valid number or not.

Comment: I checked and it doesn't work when I consider other numbers... I guess the way to go is to get a list of alpha-2 (the country ID) from a module like `country_list` and then make a for loop.

Comment: I also tried this and it gives:  'Etc/Unknown' maybe you can use this instead
`from phonenumbers import timezone`
`timezone.time_zones_for_number(phone_number)`